# How to print two A6 pages to one A4 page

Tags: printing

Good afternoon

I would like to print two A6 pages on one A4 page, on all page, the picture on the right side. I tried to use this code, below, but the result isn't that what I want, the picture on the left side.

Do you have some ideas?

Thank you for help.

P.S. -gram.pdf is A PDF file - A6 pages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1,3},nup=1x2,frame,delta=2cm 0]{gram.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pictures1]

Comment: With other words: You want to use A6 to behave like A5 printed in A4? ;-)

Comment: Have you tried the `landscape` option for `\includepdf`?

Comment: No, I haven't. How to do it?

Comment: Try `\includepdf[landscape,pages={1,3},nup=1x2,frame,delta=2cm 0]{gram.pdf}`

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič: You try to get two A5 pages actually on the A4 format (which is the natural next subdivision. A6 is only a quarter of a A4 page, so you have to blast the A6 pages up to A5 then)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing left to do with your your MWE is to rotate the page. For this the `pdfpages` has the option `landscape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

\begin{document}

\includepdf[landscape,pages={1,3},nup=1x2,frame,delta=2cm 0]{gram.pdf}

\end{document}
```